# Symfony/php : Call to a member function render() on null

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I got started on a school project on symfony and i'm trying to send some mails via Swift_Mailer Bundle for symfony but i'm at a dead-end

I'm creating an instance of a mailer and renderer to send the mail and render the mail but it seems that they stay at null even with my __construct() method.

I really can't figure out what I messed up in this

Could you help me ?

The UserController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Notification\ContactNotification;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user", name="user")
     */
    public function createUser(ContactNotification $notification): Response
    {
        // you can fetch the EntityManager via $this->getDoctrine()
        // or you can add an argument to the action: createProduct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = new User();
        $user->setMailAddress('jhondoe@gmail.com');


        // tell Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
        $entityManager->persist($user);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
        $entityManager->flush();
        $notification->notify($user);

        return new Response('Saved new user with email '.$user->getMailAddress());

    }
}
```

The User.php entity (pretty basic, just an email property to send a mail to with an id for the database)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $MailAddress;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getMailAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->MailAddress;
    }

    public function setMailAddress(string $MailAddress): self
    {
        $this->MailAddress = $MailAddress;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the ContactNotification.php where where the mailer and renderer are supposed to be initialized

```php
<?php
namespace App\Notification;

use App\Entity\User;
use Twig\Environment;

class ContactNotification {

    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var Environnement
     */
    private $renderer;

    
    public function __contrsuct( \Swift_Mailer $mailer, Environment $renderer){
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->renderer = $renderer; 
    }

    public function notify(User $user){
        dump($this->mailer);
        dump($this->renderer);
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Mail test'))
        ->setFrom('noreply@test.fr')
        ->setTo('contact@soutenance.fr')
        ->setReplyTo($user->getMailAddress());
        /* ->setBody($this->renderer->render(
            // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
            'email/contact.html.twig',
            ['user' => $user]
        ),
        'text/html'
    );  */
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope by now you have noticed, that your constructor has a spelling error and it needs to be `__construct` and not `__contrsuct`. cheers.

Comment: Lmao i feel rly dumb, ty for that one